# Spring controller returns 500 server error after updating Spring version to 4.2.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was using Spring `4.1.8.RELEASE` version without any issue in my application. I have basic setup with Spring controllers which are serving as REST resources and have defined the following resource:

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/emailvalidation",
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity userEmailValidation(
            @Valid @RequestBody UserEmailValidationRequest request, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    validator.validate(ErrorCode.class, bindingResult);

    backendClient().validateUserEmail(request);

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

This was a properly working resource, and, in case validation passed, it was returning a successful response with HTTP status 201.

The problem is that, after updating the version to `4.2.3.RELEASE`, the resource always returns HTTP status 500.

Is there a new way of handling those kind of resources where I do want to do a POST, however there is no response data? I could not find any update about this, neither any issue.

Comment: 500 can be caused by many reasons, you should provide more detailed error logs

Comment: There are no error logs unfortunately, the method is process correctly, however the client received 500 always.

Comment: is the code even executed?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker yes, the code is executed successfully, without any error. However client receives 500 - and no errors at all , as I mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: And what does the browser console say?

Comment: @vtorosyan You meant server received 500 or client? I thought in your OP it was the server complaining. If server is facing 500, there should be error log prints to the console.

Comment: @JasonZ By definition, the server sends the 500. And no, by default Spring MVC does not log every 500 errors (at least above DEBUG level). So it is a good idea to make the log more verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that there was a Runtime exception which was causing the method to return `500` status.

I have a `LoggingFilter` which is extending `org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter`. In this filter I have a method which is trying to get response output stream (see the usage below)

```
byte[] responseData = response.getOutputBuffer();
String payload = new String(responseData).replace("\n", "");
message.append(";payload=").append(payload);
```

With previous versions up to 4.2, `response.getOutputBuffer()` was returning `byte[0]` when there was no response data, so all was fine. 
Since version 4.2.*, this has been changed to return `null` instead in case there is no response data. This was causing the `NullPointerException`, which was producing `500 Server Error`.

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException. Somewhere in your code. This has nothing to do with Spring Framework. Unfortunately the exception may not print on console.

Error 500: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 500